# Phone Number Input - Focus on Next Input when Current is Full

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am looking to make a set of 3 form inputs for a phone number that automatically focuses on the next set of digits when the first is full.

My form is this string of HTML:

```
myLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {

     // here you call `bindPopup` with a string of HTML you create - the feature
     // properties declared above are available under `layer.feature.properties`

var content = '<div class="tooltip-header">Store Name<\/div>' +
              '<div class="tooltip-address">' + layer.feature.properties.address1 + '<div\/>' +
              '<div class="tooltip-address">' + layer.feature.properties.address2 + '<div\/>' +
              '<br>'+
              '<div class="tooltip-phoneLabel">' + layer.feature.properties.phoneLabel + '<div\/>'+
              '<br>'+
              '<div class="phone-input">'+
              '<input class="phone-input" name="phone-input" type="tel" size="3" maxlength="3" placeholder="555">  '+
              '<input class="phone-input" name="phone-input" type="tel" size="3" maxlength="3" placeholder="555">  '+
              '<input class="phone-input" name="phone-input" type="tel" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="5555">'+
              '<\/div>';

     layer.bindPopup(content);
});
```

Comment: Just some advice with a solution like this (having done something like this in the past): What about extensions? Ex. 1-800-123-1234 x 78923? Almost all businesses will have extensions. What about foreign phone numbers that follow a different format? What about foreign phone numbers that follow a similar format, but require a + country code? The worst thing in the world is to lose a potential customer because of a technology limitation of your contact form...

Comment: I appreciate the input @dman2306 this is a form for signing up for text notifications for a US store so I think we'll be okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following example to achieve what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('body').on('keyup', 'input.phone-input', function(){
        if($(this).val().length === this.size){
            var inputs = $('input.phone-input');
            inputs.eq(inputs.index(this) + 1).focus();
        }
    });

});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/fmrnbvkh/3/)

Comment: Anywhere inside `$(document).ready(function(){  HERE  });`. See my answer again, I change it a bit ;)